# Pyomo: Is this triple summation objective function formatted correctly?

Tags: pyomo

I am writing a Pyomo model and trying to code the following mathematical constraint:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{t=1}^T 5I_{ijt} + 10L_{ijt}I_{ijt}  $$
where $L_{ijt}$  is binary.

However, I am hoping that I could get someone to clarify if what I have written in my model makes sense:

```
def objective_rule(model):
    return sum (sum (sum (model.obj[i,j,t] for i in model.Iset ) for j in model.Jset ) for t in model.Tset )
model.damages = Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=minimize)

def obj_rule(model, i,j,t):
    return model.obj[i,j,t] == 5*model.inf_b4treat[i,j,t] + 10 *model.level1[i,j,t]*model.inf_b4treat[i,j,t]
model.object = Constraint(model.Iset, model.Jset, model.Tset, rule=obj_rule)
```

I am getting a couple of strange results and having debugged my model I am thinking that it might be due to my objective function not being formatted properly. To clarify, the reason that I chose to create an additional object called `model.obj[i,j,t]` is so that I could access the objective function values after I solve the model.

I would appreciate any corrections.

Comment: It might be easier for people to help you if you can provide a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which demonstrates your "strange results".

Comment: I think you probably can change it to `sum(model.obj[i,j,t] for i in model.Iset for j in model.Jset for t in model.Tset)` but it should be the same. Can you provide additional information on the other variables? What type are they and what bounds do they have?

Comment: To @KevinDalmeijer's comment, here's OR.SE's version of the [minimum working example](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/what-is-a-minimal-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-write-one) page.

Comment: Cool, good to know we have our own!

Comment: The expression given in your example seems like it is not a constraint but the way you coded it in your Pyomo code, it is the right-hand side of a constraint for which the left-hand side expression is missing in your example. Is that correct? What would be the complete constraint rule?

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to add so many "sum" while writing constraints or objective function in Pyomo, write your objective function like this

```
def objective_rule(model):
    return sum((5*model.inf_b4treat[i,j,t] + 10*model.level1[i,j,t]*model.inf_b4treat[i,j,t]) for i in model.Iset for j in model.Jset for t in model.Tset)
model.objective_rule = Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=minimize, doc='Objective Function')
```

You can check your constraints or objective function using

```
model.objective_rule.pprint()
```